# Is body element a block-level or in-line element?

Tags: html

I've looked on the MDN for any indication whether the HTML body element is a block-level or inline-level element:

[Inline Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) /
[Block-level Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Neither of these mentions anything about the body element except:

> Block-level elements may appear only within a < body > element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

W3 defined it as a block.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-BODY

It is displayed as a block by default.
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/body.html

Answer (score 6):

HTML4 classified elements into the ["block-level"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#didx-block-level) and ["inline"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#didx-inline) categories.

However, HTML5 doesn't have that notion. Instead, it was moved to CSS: [block-level elements and block boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes) and [inline-level elements and inline boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes).

According to HTML5, the [`body`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-body-element) element belongs to the [sectioning root](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#sectioning-root) category. And that's all.

However, in [Rendering - The page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-page), HTML5 specifies that `body` should be displayed as a block by default:

> ```
> html, body { display: block; }
> ```

Then, according the the definition in CSS, it will be block-level, unless you override that style.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer—because whatever the old HTML4 spec said is now irrelevant and no longer authoritative in any way; instead what the current HTML spec (HTML5) states is what matters. (And as this answer alludes to, “block” and ”inline” now only have relevance in terms of styleas values for the CSS `display` property—they no longer have meaning in HTML itself.)

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb (aka. how HTML4 did it): Since it can't just hold text but also block elements, it's a block element.

There are now some exceptions since HTML5 was introduced though, like being allowed to wrap anchors around pretty much anything.

Comment: CSS allows inline elements to contain blocks.

Comment: But HTML doesn't, does it? As a rule of thumb at least. Only element I can think of is an anchor.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. That's how MDN section on block-level elements explains it: _The **"block-level"** category roughly corresponds to the category of flow content in HTML5, while **"inline"** corresponds to phrasing content, but there are additional categories_ The MDN page on block-level elements just didn't include the body element as part of their list ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)).

Comment: HTML no longer has the block and inline notions. Yes, `a` is an example of an inline-by-default element which can contain block-by-default elements. But you can also take a `div` and style it with `display: inline`, it will now be inline and HTML doesn't care about that so it can still contain block-by-default elements.

Comment: You could do the `div` thing before HTML5. This is not about styling. There are rules as to which elements an element may contain. Like a `tr` may only contain `td` elements.