# How to determine the size of flex items without using percents (%)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's suppose that this is my HTML, meaning I have an unknown number of div elements:

```
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

I want to use Flexbox to arrange the elements in a way that each row includes only 3 elements.

[image]

This is the CSS code that I wrote that can make it:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 20%;
  border: solid;
}
```

Using percents to define size may be sometimes cumbersome. I want to ask if there is a way to write the CSS code in this case without using percents.

When I remove `width:100%` from `html` and `body`, I get something weird:

[image]

```css
html, body {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 20%;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could also use em or rem values. But i would stay with the % values. It will take now a little bit more work, but as result you will get a nice responsive design. And don't forget, flexboxes are not supported by internet explorer.

Comment: so there is no way to do it without percents? Properties such as flex-shrink, flex-basis and flex-grow cannot help here ?

Comment: The first comment is incorrect in terms of browser support. Flexbox is not supported by IE < 10.

Comment: Michael_B, it's cumbersome, because when you define a size with percents, you must also define the size of all ancestors of this element. It may be not elegant.

Comment: @Michael_B, yes. I have tried. For example, I deleted 'width: 100%' from html,body and I got something very ugly.

Comment: Post your full code so that we can reproduce the problem. When using percentage widths, there is no need to define widths on the parent elements.

Comment: @Michael_B, I edited the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ask if there is a way to write the CSS code in this case
>   without using percents.

Yes, as being said, there is more than percent, like `em`, `rem`, `vw`/`vh`, that can be used, though I personally find `%` to be one of the better, as it help you to scale your site very well.

> Using percents to define size may sometimes be cumbersome. For
>   example, I deleted `width: 100%` from `html, body` rule and I got something
>   very ugly.

Yes, though that is expected behavior, as the `body` does not behave as a standard block element in HTML5 and set as `display: flex;`, [Is body element a block level or inline element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566180/is-body-element-a-block-level-or-in-line-element), which the `html` elements does.

So when we know that, we can utilize `flexbox`'s properties properly, by doing something like this, where we make the `html` element the first flex container, the `body` its flex item and as well the second flex container, for the `div` elements.

In addition, to overcome the issue using percent on height, where all ancestors need a height, I used viewport units `vh`.

```css
html {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  flex: 1;                         /*  expand and take all available space */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 20vh;                    /*  20vh equals 20% of the viewport */
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

---

I would recommend though, to use a `div`, instead of the `body`, as a container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.container div {
  width: 30%;
  height: 20vh;                    /*  20vh equals 20% of the viewport */
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're sizing your flex items based on the full height and width of the `body` element, you can use ***viewport units*** instead of ***percentage units***:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div {
  flex: 1 0 30vw;
  height: 20vh;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

From the spec:

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the `vw`, `vh`, `vmin`, `vmax` units**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the
>   initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial
>   containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.
>
> - **vw unit** - Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
> - **vh unit** - Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing
>     block.
> - **vmin unit** - Equal to the smaller of `vw` or `vh`.
> - **vmax unit** - Equal to the larger of `vw` or `vh`.